# list with swipe event

Tags: list, jquery-mobile, swipe, photoswipe

I want to developed a list, `<ul><li></li>...<ul>`, that shows every `<li>`element separately, and user must have to swipe from right to left to see next element.

[Photoswipe](http://www.photoswipe.com) do the that, but I need to show images with maps areas instead of `<a href...><img ... /> </a>`.

Do you know how can make a list where every list element is shown in one page, and user must have to swipe an element to see the next one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iScroll` to do this. It makes it possible to scroll horizontally, as it is shown [here](http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/carousel/). It also works with `jQuery Mobile` ([here](http://apexeleven.com/stackoverflow/iScroll/second.html) is an example for that).

Beyond this, you can take a look at [iScroll's website](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) and their code and examples at [GitHub](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll).

Comment: It looks great. I will check it and I tell you. Thanks.